# DNS SOA type lookup in GoLang

Tags: go, dns, nslookup

I'm very new to GoLang. So, I'm supposed to do an `nslookup` of a DNS that I read from a file. When I do `nslookup example-dns.com` from my terminal, I receive all details such as the server, address and all records associated with that dns. However, when I try the same via code (I'm using the following library: [GoLang check-soa.go](https://github.com/darkoperator/golang-dns/tree/master/contrib/check-soa)), I obtain an error saying `Missing port number`.

So I tried with various port numbers (53, 443, etc - not random, of course) and I receive a `No such host` error. And when I try `nslookup example-dns.com:<port number>` via the terminal, I receive `** server can't find example-dns:<port-number>: NXDOMAIN` error.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
    import (
    "github.com/miekg/dns"
    "fmt"
    // other imports
    )

    //other code ...

    func checkSOA() {
    str:="google.com:53"
    m := new(dns.Msg)
    m.SetQuestion(str, dns.TypeSOA)

    c := new(dns.Client)
    r, p, q := c.Exchange(m, str)
    fmt.Println("r is: ", r)
    fmt.Println("p is: ", p)
    fmt.Println("q is: ", q)

    if r != nil && r.Rcode != dns.RcodeSuccess {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get an valid answer")
        fmt.Println("%v\n", r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your source code somewhere? You should not include the port number in the name you want to lookup. If you want to change the port used when talking to the DNS server you can use `-port=` i think.

Comment: @MattiasWadman just added some code! Hope this helps

Comment: You seem to be mixing various stuff. Your code is doing an SOA request for the name google.com:53  This is not a valid name. Port has nothing to do there. `str` should be the name you want to query. The second parameter of Exchange is the nameserver you query + ":" + the port. So you can not use `str` both for `SetQuestion` and for `Exchange`.  You have to be clear on the separation between who (which nameserver) you query and what you query it for.

Comment: Also if you use `check-soa.go` you do not need to deal with all that stuff, `localQuery` does most of it for you. You can then study how the rest of the code in the same file uses the result from `localQuery` to display various stuff.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You're right about that, that worked for me. Thanks! :)